# Pandoc: does not include input files

Tags: latex, docx, pandoc, adobe-indesign, pdflatex

I have a LaTeX file that refers to many other single files. Those files are included/referenced by

```
\input{somefolder/somefile}
```

**Context:** Now I'm trying to import the LaTeX to Adobe Indesign by converting it to Docx first and then to Indesign using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html).

**Problem:** But somehow Pandoc is generating the output just from the main tex file (the entry point) and does not follow the inputs. What am I doing wrong?

> pandoc main.tex -t docx -o main.docx

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of pandoc seem to support the `\input{}` construct (tried on pandoc 1.19.2.1).

Also, why go via docx? Try:

```
pandoc input.tex -o output.icml
```

and [place the generated ICML in your InDesign document](http://networkcultures.org/digitalpublishing/2014/10/08/markdown-to-indesign-with-pandoc-via-icml/).

Comment: So i need kind of Pandoc config file? Thought it's done by one line. Installed the most recent version of Pandoc. According to this link (https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/supported-file-formats-indesign-cs5.html#main_Open) ICML isn't directly supported?! Need to test it. Thx

Comment: Because I'm not the one using Indesign - it's our marketing design department. So I need to ask them if they are capable of using ICML. Anyway, converting the tex file doesn't work anyway :(

Comment: you can also convert multiple files using `pandoc *.tex` etc. if the `\input` doesn't work. Also feel free to ask on pandoc-discuss but you'll have to provide your input files...

Comment: I gave up on Pandoc since I'm getting tons of errors depending on the input. We could create a Word file from the Latex generated PDF using Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: 2.2.3.2 does not support this but complains that it could not load the include file.